# Sending data to Listview of another activity

Tags: java, android, android-listview

After pressing the button I would like to go to the second activity, enter the data in the second activity and then return to the main activity, but having data in `ListView`. This is my code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    ListView listView;
    String name;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> nameList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.CarList);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });



        nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        nameList.addAll(Arrays.asList(name));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.element, nameList);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

            name = i.getStringExtra("name");

        }
    }

}
```

And this is my **SecondActivity:**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    Button button2;
    String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button);


    }

    public void finish() {

        Intent i = new Intent();
        name = editText.getText().toString();
        i.putExtra("name", name);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

What could I change to make the application work? Because now I only get the message that: app has stopped, but I don't receive information about any error.

Comment: Change the name of this `finish()` method because there is a predefined method having this name, when you change it let me know if still there is problem

Answer (score 0):

> After pressing the button I would like to go to the second activity, enter the data in the second activity and then return to the main activity, but having data in ListView.
>
> What could I change to make the application work? Because now I only get the message that: app has stopped, but I don't receive information about any error.

This is simply because you've incorrectly thinking that [`Activity.finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) is always called whenever you close the activity. But it never be called by the Android. Take a look for this Lifecyle picture from [Activity-lifecycle concepts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle):

[image: Activity-lifecycle concepts]

you can see that only `onStop()` then `onDestroy()` is called when activity is closed.

You need to call the `finish()` method manually to send your intent. Or, the better way, create a method that only build and set the intent for the result. Something like this:

```
private void prepareResult(String name) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("name", name);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
}
```

then call it whenever you want to close your activity:

```
String name = editText.getText().toString();
prepareResult(name);
finish();
```

Or you can override the [`onBackPressed()`](http://public%20void%20onBackPressed%20()) to also handing the back pressed, like the following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    name = editText.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("name", name);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

  // The default implementation simply finishes the current activity
  // see the documentation.
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I made the changes according to your instructions, namely: I created the prepareResult method, and then I call it when the button is pressed. 
Unfortunately I still get such a message, 
Is not this line of code problem a problem? nameList.addAll(Arrays.asList(name));  
It seems to me that this line should be in the onActivityResult method, to which the value of name is passed.

Comment: You're correct, the `nameList.addAll(Arrays.asList(name)); in `onCreate()` should be removed because you didn't have the value for `name` variable yet. Previously, I thought you've implementing the onActivityResult to handle the value.

To fix it, you need to modify your `onActivityResult()` with something like this:

    `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

            String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }`